# Collections of Sets without Subsets

Tags: combinatorics

Is the following known?  It seems related to codes and/or Ramsey theory.

Given $r$, for what values of $n,k$, does there exist a collection of $n$ sets whose union contains $k$ elements such that none of these sets is contained in the union of at most $r$ of the sets.

For example given $r<3$ choosing $n=3$, $k=4$ satisfies the requirement, because of {{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}}. More generally if $r=2$ then any $n$ and $k>n$ satisfies the requirement by generalizing this example.

For $r=1$ with any $n$, and $k>\lceil log_2(n)\rceil$ one can satisfy the requirement by numbering the sets in order and using the binary representation of their number (like a Hamming code). This argument can be used to show (information theoretic) lower bounds of $k>\lceil r log_2(n)\rceil$.